# Why aren’t my African dwarf frogs eating

Tags: diet, frogs

Well I just got my two African dwarf frogs and neither of them have been eating and they have no shown any interest in eating what so ever

Comment: Have you been briefed about the environmental requirements of these frogs? How warm and humid their enclosure must be and what kind of substrate and food they like? Frogs are cold-blooded and slow down their metabolism in cold conditions. That can lead to short periods of reduced activity and appetite, but can be detrimental if it's too cold for too long.

Comment: How long have you had them? How long have they not been eating?

Comment: Please answer the questions in the comments! This is important information and you will get good answers if you give good information :) Also you can use the "edit" button and add the information directly into your question